# Shape ID is lost after converting a shapefile into a raster in QGIS

Tags: raster, vector, gdal-rasterize

[image]Instead of a landclass having the value 1 (my previous shapefile ID), the raster classes have the below values after shapefile conversion.

The above input values and gdal command was used

```
gdal_rasterize -l HanselSquare -a id -tr 100.0 100.0 -te 4130900.0 2799300.0 4230800.0 2899100.0 -ot Int32 -of GTiff
```

How do I keep the shapefile ID after conversion?

[image]

Comment: Vector to Raster conversion tool, with the following setting as in the image.

Comment: you should use int instead of float

Comment: I have just tried that, but I still got the same result. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: Remove festen Wert and Leerwert.

Comment: I have applied that, it resulted in the landclass having two 0's.

Comment: When you run the job, it should create a command "gdal_rasterize ......". Can you paste the full command that it creates.

Comment: sure, as follows :

Comment: gdal_rasterize -l HanselSquare -a id -tr 100.0 100.0 -te 4130900.0 2799300.0 4230800.0 2899100.0 -ot Int32 -of GTiff

Comment: Please [Edit] the question is response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those would help you to make them sift through comments for critical information.